# IE 8 issue - HTML Parsing error : unable to modify the parent container element before the child element is closed (KB 927917)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, internet-explorer-8

If i comment this below code from my master page, I am not getting the error in IE 8. The rest all browsers works fine with this code. Its only IE 8 that messes up. But the users are using IE 8 only

Code at end of my master page :

```
    </form>
</div>

    <script src="../Uploadedfiles/System/Scripts/layerslider/jQuery/jquery-easing-1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Uploadedfiles/System/Scripts/layerslider/js/layerslider.kreaturamedia.jquery-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            $('#layerslider').layerSlider({
                skin: 'lightskin',
                skinsPath: '../uploadedfiles/System/Scripts/layerslider/skins/'
            });
        }); 
    </script>

</html>
```

How can i solve this issue ? I have read this [link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/html-parsing-error-unable-to-modify-the-parent/e64759e0-d344-42d6-b1d8-0ce27504dd71) 
And when tried doing it, the error is not popping up and the site doesn't load !!!

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be missing the `</body>` tag.